# Implementing Twitter API application-only authentication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to create a simple web app that can export a list of people you follow ("friends"). I am using node.js with the [twitter package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter). I want to first use my **Consumer Key** and **Consumer Secret** to get a **Bearer Token** as shown [here](https://github.com/m-coding/twitter-application-only-auth). Then I want to use the **Consumer Secret**, **Consumer Key**, and newly created **Bearer Token** to authenticate with twitter.

My problem is that I am getting my Bearer Token with the asynchronous function `request.post`, and I can't figure out how to pass the token to the function I use to authenticate with twitter. It's asynchronous, so I can't just do (pseudocode)

```
function getBearerToken() { return request.post(bearerTokenParameters) }
var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_secret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
    consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
    bearer_token: getBearerToken()})
```

Because `request` is asynchronous and doesn't return the response. Tried doing something like (pseudocode)

```
request-promise.post(bearerTokenParameters)
    .next( (response) => {
        return new Twitter({
            consumer_secret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
            consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
            bearer_token: response.bearer_token 
        })
    }
)
```

But now I can't use the `Twitter` object I've just created.

I know that I could just generate my Bearer Token using a [script](https://github.com/m-coding/twitter-application-only-auth) and then enter it in manually but it seems there must be a better way to do it if I already have all the information.

Comment: Since you know you can generate the bearer token before hand, why are you choosing to do it in code?

Comment: @JoshAbraham I realize I can do it beforehand, but I feel like it shouldn't be necessary. I am making the application on glitch.com, and I like that I can develop it anywhere, even a mobile device. Needing to generate the token every time I changed the API keys would hamper that a little bit. If I can't solve this problem I'll probably do that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var client;
function getBearerToken() 
{ 
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       request.post(bearerTokenParameters).then(function(response) {
           return resolve(response);
       }).catch(function(err) {
           return reject(err)
       }) 
   }
}

getBearerToken()
    .then( (response) => {
        client = new Twitter({
            consumer_secret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
            consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
            bearer_token: response.bearer_token 
        })
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work; `client` doesn't change because `request` (and `request-promise`, a version that allows you to use it with promises) is asynchronous. Unless I'm supposed to do everything with the `client` object inside that callback?

Comment: Updated my answer. Regarding your asynchronous comment, that's what promises are for. To make the part of code execute only when the promise has been resolved. Hope that works.

Comment: Thank you. In order to simplify the number of callbacks that I have to do, I'll probably just enter the Bearer Token by hand so I can just authenticate on initializing.